# Decimal marshaling in COM-Interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have COM object method with signature

```
HRESULT _stdcall Method1([in] int ms);
```

Next, i call this method from C# by reflection:

```
 ...

decimal ms = 100.5m;
comType.InvokeMember("Method1", flags, null, comObject, new object[] { ms });

 ...
```

Is this call correct ? I mean how **decimal** ms will be marshaled to **int** ?

This code works if i create instance by Activator

```
var comType= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyCom.Server", false);
var comObject= Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You know that this cannot work. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It expects an int, why do you think you can pass a decimal of all types?

Comment: <pre>var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyCom.Server", false);
     var comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

Comment: sorry, i mean that IT'S WORK

Comment: It cannot work. You cannot fit a decimal in an int.

Comment: A decimal would be converted into an integer this means you lose the percision of the decimal value.  The default behavior often is to either round up or down depending on the language used.  In a case like this since .5 is odd its likely going to round up to 101 although you really should convert it yourself and apply the rounding of your choice to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet makes an early-bound call, using the Runtime Callable Wrapper that was created when you added a reference to the COM server.  It is not going to enjoy you passing a decimal when the argument type is int, Reflection won't convert argument values for you.

The second snippet makes a late-bound call, using IDispatch::Invoke().  The decimal is converted to a VARIANT of type VT_DEC.  The IDispatch implementation in the COM server then converts that variant to the required argument type.  The COM automation helper function VarI4FromDec() probably does that, depends if the server implemented IDispatch itself or left it up to the stock implementation.

Since you are already using an RCW, neither code snippet makes much sense.  Just use comObject.Method1(ms).  The C# compiler will coerce the decimal for you.  If you favor using late binding, slow but safe, you really want to favor the *dynamic* keyword in C# version 4 and up.